# Host Name Vs Canonical Host Name

Tags: java, ip-address, hostname, inetaddress, canonical-name

Can anyone please explain me the difference between Host Name and Canonical Host Name?

I am currently using InetAddress class to fetch host name using the IP Address. I came across these 2 APIs.
So I am just wondering, which one I should opt for?

Comment: Canonical host name. http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CanonicalHostNames

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are a few difference between the two:

- [`getCanonicalHostName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName%28%29) will attempt to resolve the [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name). Therefore, you would get *foo.mycompany.com* whereas [`getHostName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostAddress%28%29) might just return *foo*.
- `getCanonicalHostName()` will always do a reverse DNS lookup, whereas `getHostName()` would return the stored hostname if you supplied one in the `InetAddress` constructor.

I suspect you will be wanting to use `getCanonicalHostName()` if you are intending to map IP addresses to host names.