# Using InetAddress to find DNS host name on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, dns

I'm trying to get the host name of the for the machine I am running on in Heroku. What i want to get is something like this: `https://gentle-hollows-7643-243.com`

What I am using right now is the [getCannoncialHostName](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()) inside of the `InetAddress` class. This is giving me a value like this:

```
String hostName = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost.getCannonicalHostName
//returns the following
//be24dfaf-671d-4c37-8468-e1826ea26507.prvt.dyno.rt.heroku.com
```

This is not what I am expecting to receive, which is `https://gentle-hollows-7643-243.com`

Am I misunderstanding the intent for `getCannonicalHostName` or is this working incorrectly because the Heroku architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to get what you're after. The Heroku dyno runs behind a proxy that routes traffic to it. So the actual host name for the process is not the one you'd use from a browser. Another possible solution is to set a config var like `APP_NAME` to "gentle-hollows-7643-243" and then use that in your app like `System.getenv("APP_NAME");`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this

getCanonicalName() method will return fully qualified domain name

[Host Name Vs Canonical Host Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669076/host-name-vs-canonical-host-name)

Comment: So what method would I want to be using to return what I specified in the OP?